# Groovy / Grails - How to get class instance from String?

Tags: class, grails, groovy

I'm trying to derive the class instance of a groovy class from the name of string.

For example, I'd like to do some code along these lines:

```
def domainName

domainName = "Patient"

// but following line doesn't work, domainName is a String
def domainInstance = domainName.get(1);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Grails way would be to use [GrailsApplication#getArtefact](http://www.grails.org/doc/1.0.3/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/GrailsApplication.html#getArtefact%28java.lang.String%2C%20java.lang.String%29). e.g.,

```
def domainInstance = grailsApplication.getArtefact("Domain",domainName)?.
        getClazz()?.get(1)
```

The advantage of doing it this way as opposed to `Class.forName` is that if there is no domain class with that name, `getArtefact` just returns null instead of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 2):

This will work:

```
   Class.forName("Patient",  false, Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader).get(1)
```

Comment: what I was looking for, but the next one covers null. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score -3):

Well,

1. Try to implement your code using packages
2. Try this code: I don't know if it will work ok?

`def domainInstance = Class.forName("Patient").newInstance()`